# Escape cURL command in Yaml which contains quotes and apostrophes

Tags: curl, escaping, yaml, gitlab-ci

I've got this cURL command:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "A new version has been deployed to production."}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I need to use this in a GitLab CI file which has the Yaml support.
The Yaml parser does not accept it. Normally I would surround it in quotes but I already use both quotes and apostrophes in the command.

This is how the command looks right now.

How can I escape the sequence properly?

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "A new version has been deployed to production."}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a block scalar:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: |-
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "A new version has been deployed to production."}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

`|` starts a literal block scalar, `-` tells YAML to discard the trailing newline (which would otherwise be part of the scalar). For readability, you can use a folded block scalar instead (newlines will be converted to spaces):

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: >-
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"text":
    "A new version has been deployed to production."}'
    https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Finally, it is also possible to use double quotes, as long as you escape the double quotes inside the scalar (newlines are also folded into spaces):

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: 
    "curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={\"text\":
     \"A new version has been deployed to production.\"}' 
     https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: @Astronaut [The docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script) say you should use a list for that. You can use all those scalar styles for each item in the list (e.g. `- >-` starts a list item with a folded block scalar in it).

Comment: Hum indeed i tried but got CI lint giving me complaints

Comment: The problem I am having is that using double quotes the variable is not getting parsed... since it is a string hehehe... its a bit of a pain